# Am I hurting performance or using bad practice by including css within my static block?

Tags: magento2, css, static-block

When I create a new section for my home page or a block for a category header is it bad practice to include  css within that block? My thought process is that when I want to remove or change that section I can go to one spot to control or disable everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To emmbed the `CSS` in a block is not the end of the world but it's not a good practice in some cases and why ?

When user visit your website, browser downloads the `HTML` of the current page plus the `css file`, when user switch to another page, browser only needs to download the `HTML` of that new page, and not `CSS` file because it's cached from the first visit, so it doesn't need to be downloaded again. This makes a big difference especially if you have a big `CSS` file.

Contrary if you embed you css for each file, block, Browser need to download it every time !

Also the no code optimization, for exemple if you have 5 block with 5 sliders with the same design and css, in this case you will embed your css code 5 times for each block, while you can do in css file just one time for all.

**Conclusion:** if your embed a not very large `css`, you can do it, but it's still better to put it in stylesheet file.